# Char encoding problem in listlisting

Tags: unicode, french, listingsutf8

I would like to use listlisting and post commented source code in french. This is the complete document :

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
%% Langage et police utilisée
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}

\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapebegin={/**},
  escapeend={*/},
  tabsize=3
  }

\begin{document}
Test écriture.
\begin{lstlisting}
 /**
     * Compilation problem because there is é or ç or ê or ï
     * @param Description
     * @return Description
     */
    public static void main(String argc[]) {
        System.out.println("_Compilation problem"); // This create a compilation problem
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

I have two errors :
Babel error

> unknow option 'francais'

(I tried frenchb but same problem).

The second error is !

> Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@EC�
>   (U+9EA9) ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode char �\lst@EC� (U+9EA7)

...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please also have a look at the various examples of the `literate` option out there.

Answer (score 1):

First let me reference the manual of `babel` and `listings`:

`babel` says

> **4.6 Changes in babel version 3.6**
>
> Support for typesetting french texts is much enhanced; the file
>   francais.ldf is now replaced by frenchb.ldf which is maintained by
>   Daniel Flipo.

However both options `french` and `francais` will work. `babel.sty` says:

```
\DeclareOption{francais}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}
\DeclareOption{french}{\bbl@load@language{frenchb}}%
```

`listings` says (page 15)

> Thus, if you use the a package that supports multibyte characters,
>   such as the CJK or ucs packages for Chinese and UTF-8 characters, you
>   must avoid let- ting listings process the extended characters

However you can work with the option `literate` to get an output.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{listings,xcolor}
%% Langage et police utilisée

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\lstset{%
            inputencoding=utf8,
            extendedchars=true,
            literate=%
            {é}{{\'{e}}}1
            {è}{{\`{e}}}1
            {ê}{{\^{e}}}1
            {ë}{{\¨{e}}}1
            {û}{{\^{u}}}1
            {ù}{{\`{u}}}1
            {â}{{\^{a}}}1
            {à}{{\`{a}}}1
            {î}{{\^{i}}}1
            {ô}{{\^{o}}}1
            {ç}{{\c{c}}}1
            {Ç}{{\c{C}}}1
            {É}{{\'{E}}}1
            {Ê}{{\^{E}}}1
            {À}{{\`{A}}}1
            {Â}{{\^{A}}}1
            {Î}{{\^{I}}}1,
    }


\lstset{frame=tb,
  language=Java,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\small\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  stringstyle=\color{mauve},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  escapebegin={/**},
  escapeend={*/},
  tabsize=3
  }

\begin{document}
Test écriture. 
\begin{lstlisting}
 /**
     * Compilation problem because there is é\ or ç\ or ê\ or\ î
     * @param Description
     * @return Description
     */
    public static void main(String argc[]) {
        System.out.println("_Compilation problem"); // This create a compilation problem
    }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think that `\usepackage[francais]{babel}` should work.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks. You are right. It's always the best to have a look at the sty file ;-)